# Fixing hapless macros

Tags: common-lisp

After some trial & error, I've managed to code a macro mashup to print the names & values of several variables (for debugging). It seems to work, but I'd like to see how to code this more "professionally"?

```
(defmacro prt1 (var)
  ;Print a single variable and its value.
  `(progn (princ (symbol-name ',var)) (princ " = ") (princ ,var) (terpri)))

(defmacro prt (&rest vars)
  ;Print the values of a number of variable names.
  (eval `(append (list 'progn)
                 (map 'list #'(lambda (x) (list 'prt1 x)) ',vars)
                 (list (list 'terpri))
                 (list t)))) ;need to return t
```

Calling `(prt A B C)` then prints the current bindings--eg:

```
A = 1
B = 2 
C = 3
T
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defmacro prt1 (var)
  "Print a single variable and its value."
  `(format t "~a = ~a~%" ',var ,var))

(defmacro prt (&rest vars)
  "Print the values of variables."
  `(progn ,@(loop for var in vars collect `(prt1 ,var))))
```

Comment: Nice Rainer--but tried some minor modifications that just won't work!?

(defmacro prt (&rest vars)
  "Print the values of variables."
  `(progn (format t "~%")
          ,@(loop for var in vars collect `(prt1 ,var))
          (finish-output t)
          t))

Extra ~% to space output is ignored, and finish-output doesn't. The only change that does work is returning t! (I'm on SBCL.)